# How to retrieve specific key value in an array of objects within objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, foreach

I have an array originalArrayData like so:

[image]

Expanding:

[image]

The value of the first array item, which is an object, is several objects. An example of the contents of the first part of the array is as such:

```
originalArrayData = [{
    "16": {
        "id": 22,
        "grid_row_id": 5,
        "grid_col_id": 16,
        "data": "10",
        "created_at": "rertte",
        "error_mgs": null
    },
    "header": "Row 2",
    "id": 5
},
{
    "17": {
        "id": 31,
        "grid_row_id": 9,
        "grid_col_id": 17,
        "data": "14",
        "created_at": "rtyhtyjtdyj",
        "error_mgs": null
    },
    "header": "Row 1",
    "id": 6
},
{
    "18": {
        "id": 35,
        "grid_row_id": 9,
        "grid_col_id": 12,
        "data": "55",
        "created_at": "thrtuhrs",
        "error_mgs": null
    },
    "header": "Row 1",
    "id": 6
}...........
```

Let's say I have an array of ids (these numbers could be random and there isn't always 2. There could be 1, 3, etc. array items)

```
arrayOfIds: [16 , 17]
```

If the value of grid_col_id is present anywhere in the arrayOfIds, how can I retrive the 'data' value from each object and put it in its own array?

I know how to retrieve an array of all ids from each first object within the array:

```
let data = this.arrayList.map((obj) => obj.id);
```

The above yields: [5,6,7,8,9]. However, it's now correct for what I am attempting. So far I have the following:

```
var targetArr = []

this.originalArrayData.forEach(item=> {
    item.forEach(ins => {
        if(arrayOfIds.includes(ins.grid_col_id)
            targetArr.push(ins.data)
    })
})
```

which yields an error: TypeError: row.forEach is not a function

My TARGET is: [10, 14, ...]

The target contains 10 and 14 because if you look at the originalArrayData, if grid_col_id is inside arrayOfIds: [16 , 17], then we retrieve the "data" value and put it inside a new array.

How can I achieve the target array?

Comment: why not use a better data structure?

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to change the original data structure, though I would have definitely liked to

Comment: Could you create a more relavent example, there is no items with id `[16,17]` in your example,  and questions like this are much easier to answer if you supply an example input, and expected output.

Comment: Oh I think it may be the grid_col_id which you are referring to and 2 objects have grid_col_id 17 or 16. I'm not quite sure what you mean by example input and output, but the target result is the array of 'data' values given that the grid_col_id is in arrayOfIds and the input is the originalArrayData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as follows. See comments in the code for explanation

```js
let od  = [{
    "16": {
        "id": 22,
        "grid_row_id": 5,
        "grid_col_id": 16,
        "data": "10",
        "created_at": "rertte",
        "error_mgs": null
    },
    "header": "Row 2",
    "id": 5
},
{
    "17": {
        "id": 31,
        "grid_row_id": 9,
        "grid_col_id": 17,
        "data": "14",
        "created_at": "rtyhtyjtdyj",
        "error_mgs": null
    },
    "header": "Row 1",
    "id": 6
},
{
    "18": {
        "id": 35,
        "grid_row_id": 9,
        "grid_col_id": 12,
        "data": "55",
        "created_at": "thrtuhrs",
        "error_mgs": null
    },
    "header": "Row 1",
    "id": 6
}]


let filter = [16, 17];

//transform the original data into a flat array of objects
let dd = od.map(x => 
   //all property values of the object
   Object.values(x)
   //which are an object (ie filter away primitve types
   .filter(y => typeof y === "object")) 
   //flatten the array of arrays 
   .flat()
  
let result = dd  
   //filter the list of objects for the ids in the filter
  .filter(x => filter.includes(x.grid_col_id))
  //and get only the data property
  .map(x => x.data)

  console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```js
const input=[{"16":{id:22,grid_row_id:5,grid_col_id:16,data:"10",created_at:"rertte",error_mgs:null},header:"Row 2",id:5},{"17":{id:31,grid_row_id:9,grid_col_id:17,data:"14",created_at:"rtyhtyjtdyj",error_mgs:null},header:"Row 1",id:6},{"18":{id:35,grid_row_id:9,grid_col_id:12,data:"55",created_at:"thrtuhrs",error_mgs:null},header:"Row 1",id:6}];

const arrayOfIds = [16 , 17];

const format = (array) => {
    return array.reduce((result, el) => {
        const key = Object.keys(el).find((key) => 'object' === typeof el[key]);
        
        if(arrayOfIds.includes(+key)){
            result.push(+el[key].data);
        }

        return result;
    }, []);
};

console.log(format(input));
```

Comment: you forgot the filter

Comment: @derpirscher yes, you are right :) Just updated the code.

Comment: Furthermore, code-only answers are discouraged. You should add a bit of description, what you are actually doing. Either as comment in the code or in the answer itself

Answer (score -1):

Here's an alternative that more closely resembles your original attempt.

You can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [Object.hasOwn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn) and [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the key of the property with grid_col_id:

```js
const originalArrayData = [{
    "16": {
        "id": 22,
        "grid_row_id": 5,
        "grid_col_id": 16,
        "data": "10",
    },
    "header": "Row 2",
    "id": 5
},
{
    "17": {
        "id": 31,
        "grid_row_id": 9,
        "grid_col_id": 17,
        "data": "14",
    },
    "header": "Row 1",
    "id": 6
},
{
    "18": {
        "id": 35,
        "grid_row_id": 9,
        "grid_col_id": 12,
        "data": "55",
    },
    "header": "Row 1",
    "id": 6
}]

const arrayOfIds = [16, 17]
const targetArr = []

originalArrayData.forEach(d => {
    const keyOfObjectWithGridCol = 
        // Get all keys of the object as an array
        Object.keys(d)
        // Get the key of the nested object that has grid_col_id
        .find(key => Object.hasOwn(d[key], 'grid_col_id')) // Find property

    if (arrayOfIds.includes(d[keyOfObjectWithGridCol].grid_col_id)) {
        targetArr.push(d[keyOfObjectWithGridCol].data)
    }
})

console.log(targetArr) // [10, 14]
```

Comment: Depending on that something will be the "first property" of an object is quite a bad idea, because there is literally no way to guarantee that ...

Comment: @derpirscher I agree that it's not a good idea to rely on object property order. That was unacceptable laziness on my part :) - updated answer.